# How much the file system matters for storing very large amount of files and searching in them in a regular system?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

I have a large number of files (around 30 million) that are mostly below 100kb, and are stored in a 8TB SATA3 hard disk, i regularly want to search all the files for the existence of certain bytes, and currently my file system is ext4.

now considering i have no SSD or any fancy system (just a regular system with 16GB of RAM so i cant store them in RAM all the time either) does the file system really matter that much?

because i searched in google and there are a LOT of different opinions, and currently since i have ext4 its too much work to switch it to something else, so for my configuration and my task ( and lets just assume the program that i have written to search the files is optimized), if i change to another file system will i see noticeable improvement, or just a little, like 5%? and if its noticeable , which file system other than ext4 is the best?

sorry I'm not an expert when it comes to storage and file systems, tried reading the answers to similar questions but i just got confused more.

and obviously I'm not asking for an exact number for the difference, just want to understand how important is the file system in this task.

(not sure if it matters but this is my hard drive: https://www.newegg.ca/purple-wd82purz-8tb/p/N82E16822234373)

[image]

Comment: read about ZFS. Further I will suggest you just read about how well known file systems work that shall give you enough idea.

Comment: I have a couple of questions. Is this data static or does it change frequently? Is this data to be stored long-term?

Comment: Here is something to read may help you: https://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Filesystems-Benchmarked

Comment: @KGIII yes its mostly static, very rarely i add new files, its long term

Comment: @Ajay but isn't the real bottleneck here the hard drive that i have considering its not an SSD?  i mean i can read about how each of the file systems store files and such, but at the end of the day considering my hard drive, will it really matter that much? (i updated the question with the model of my hard drive)

Comment: Then, assuming you're going to continue keeping this on a single disk, you're fine just leaving it on ext4. You're not going to see any real improvements with other file systems as you'd not be taking advantage of the advanced features they offer. I'd only possibly consider changing if you intended to take advantage of said features.

Comment: SSD is definitely faster then HDD.